# Packaging MATLAB

Tags: arch-linux, packaging, matlab

I have decided to try and package [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com) for Arch Linux. The MATLAB program consists of a core program and a number of add on toolboxes. I would like to create a different independent package for each "toolbox" (or potentially subsets of toolboxes). The heart of my Arch PKGBUILD is

```
./install -t -inputFile installer_input.txt -mode silent
```

where `inputFile` is basically a list of toolboxes to be installed. If I install both `product.MATLAB` (the core MATLAB program) and `product.Signal_Processing_Toolbox` (a toolbox), everything works fine. If I only install `product.Signal_Processing_Toolbox` the installer gives me the error

> Error: One or more of the following products are required to proceed
>   with the installation:
>
> MATLAB 8.1 (Not available)
>
> You must select a folder where at least one of these products is
>   installed or select these additional products for installation.

where `MATLAB 8.1` corresponds to `product.MATLAB`. The installer is proprietary (although parts of it are open source), but I think it will be hard to hack the installer to not require `product.MATLAB`. I don't want a toolbox package to conflict with the core package. Is there a standard way of dealing with this or is it specific to MATLAB? Is it possible to remove the "core" package from the chroot environment after installing the toolbox?

Comment: As I read you need an installed product.matlab to install product.Signal_Processing_Toolbox, right? If yes, you should add 'depends' and done.

Comment: @uzsolt That is what I thought, but I need the product.matlab directory tree to to exist in my fakeroot environment even though as far as I can tell the installing the toolbox only adds files.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you've created a package from product.matlab (this the core part), you can use 'depend=product.matlab' in product.signal_processing_toolbox. And if you created a good package from product.matlab, product.signal will see the product.matlab's directory tree. Or do I something misunderstood?